# PackageMaker is failing with Invalid Certificate in Mac os X

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, packagemaker, code-signing-certificate

I have developed one Installer Package using PackageMaker  which installs different components in user machine. After signing the package its failing in another user machine with following error in logs. It works wihout any issue with un signed .pkg file

11/4/11 7:24:37 AM  installd[718]   PackageKit: Install Failed: (null)
Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=102 UserInfo=0x1004261f0 "The package “_Installer” is untrusted." Underlying Error=(Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-2147409622 UserInfo=0x10043b2e0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED") {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "The package \U201cInstaller\U201d is untrusted.";
    NSURL = "#plugin.pkg -- file://localhost/Users/sandeepakhare/Documents/%20Apps/1025/Installer/Installer.pkg";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-2147409622 UserInfo=0x10043b2e0 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED\"";

I have used Verisigned Certificate to sign the .pkg .. Please advice